# Hide command not found bash script

Tags: linux, bash

How can I hide the command not found in my bash script? Im curious because everything works great except the sloppy "command not found message"

```
read user_name
if $user_name && exit 2> /dev/null
then
        exit 0
elif egrep "^${user_name}": /etc/passwd 2> /dev/null
then
        finger $user_name
        exit 0
elif
        until egrep "^${user_name}:" /etc/passwd || $user_name && "exit"  2> /dev/null
        do
        echo "try again or type exit to quit"
        read user_name
        if egrep -i "^${user_name}": /etc/passwd
        then
                finger $user_name
        fi
        done
then
        finger $user_name
        exit 0



fi
```

This is the error im getting

```
 ./project.sh: line 49: (myusernameisherebutimhidingit): command not found
```

Comment: Don't hide it, fix it. I don't know what `if $user_name` is supposed to do, but if you want to say "if `$user_name` is non-empty" you should use `if [ -n "$user_name" ]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to run the command `$user_name` at several places, you probably want to replace `$user_name` with a check for the value of user name.

Comment: what do u mean im new to this?

Comment: @ergology: `$user_name && "exit"  2> /dev/null` does not make any sense at all. Without knowing what it's supposed to do, it's hard to tell you how to do it correctly.